# Kill running query with Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am working with sequelize and MySQL DB. I have some heavy queries that the users can cancel by clicking a 'cancel' button in the GUI.

I tried to do it with transaction but when I do `t.rollback()` the query doesn't getting killed in the DB. Is there any way to kill a query using sequelize?
I prefer to use sequlize to do it, but even getting the query ID and manually kill it is fine.

```
 .transaction(async (t) => {
        if (transaction) {
            transaction.rollback();
        }
        transaction = t;
        return db.myTable.findAll(data);
      })
      .then((data) => {
        transaction = {};

        return data;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        transaction = {};
        throw error;
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not natively supported with Sequelize. There is an [open, inactive issue](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11395) to add this ability there, with a [workaround used for PostgreSQL](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11395#issuecomment-554062917).

```js
const killableQuery = async (query, req, options = {}) => {
  const connection = await sequelize.connectionManager.getConnection();

  req.on('close', () => {
    sequelize.query(`SELECT pg_terminate_backend(${connection.processID});`)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Unable to terminate query!', error);
      });
  });
  const result = await sequelize.query(query, {
    ...options,
    transaction: { connection },
  });

  await sequelize.connectionManager.releaseConnection(connection);

  return result;
};
```

Sorry, I cannot find detail about the `processID` property and whether it corresponds to a property that MySQL tracks. If yes, one could replace the PostgreSQL statement with a [MySQL counterpart](https://scaledynamix.com/blog/how-to-kill-mysql-queries/) like:

```sql
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('KILL ',id,';') SEPARATOR ' ') 
FROM information_schema.processlist
WHERE user <> 'system user'
AND -- <condition based on processID>;
```